# readdir converts "…" in filename as "à" in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, unicode, dirent.h

I am trying to list all files in current directory and sub-directories so I can know the size of a directory by calculating the size of all the files in it. But `d_name` returns a different file name, which I can't pass to `fopen` because it changes `…` in the filename to `à`. I don't know what other characters are changed. I believe getting the `d_name` in utf-8 can fix this.

Currently the part of the code is this:

```
DIR *dr;
struct dirent *d;

dr = opendir(foldername);

if (dr != NULL) {
    for (d = readdir(dr); d != NULL; d = readdir(dr)) {
        printf("d name: %s \n", d->d_name);
    }
}
```

The actual filename is

`Write For Us. Quick guide to explain how to send… _ by Domenico Nicoli _ Dev Genius.html`

But `d_name` prints it as:

`Write For Us. Quick guide to explain how to sendà _ by Domenico Nicoli _ Dev Genius.html`

How can I fix this? I want to open, but it always gives a null pointer. Other files open neatly.

Comment: The "..." might be unicode representing the glyph, and it didn't map to POSIX UTF-8 very well.

Comment: I am not sure because I am not able to open the file. And I have been able to open other files

Comment: What platform?  Windows I think uses UTF-16 filenames internally, which don't always map to the POSIX C API well.

Comment: @Max Windows 10.  Using code blocks, so I believe GCC compiler

Comment: Can you print the filename as byte values?  Can you pipe the program output to a hexadecimal dump utility such as `od -x`?

Comment: @chqrlie+ all machines supporting Windows today are littleendian so `od -x` swaps the bytes, which tends to be confusing to less-experienced people; `od -tx1` is better, or `cat -A` (if GNU), but if this is plain Windows not WSL it doesn't have either and powershell `format-hex` is better.

Comment: If the copy'n'paste from the browser can be believed, the `…` is encoded as [U+2026](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf) (horizontal ellipsis).  That is encoded using 3 bytes in UTF-8: 0xE2, 0x80, 0xA6. In a single-byte code set such as ISO 8859-15, 0xE2 maps to LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX; the same mapping applies in MS Windows CP1250 and CP1252.  It isn't clear, therefore, where the LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE (U+00E0) is coming from. If you can't find a program to do the hex dump, it isn't hard to write a function in C that's adequate that you can call in your progrm.

Comment: please @chqrlie I don't know how to do what you are asking me to. I started studying 5 days ago.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  please I don't know how to do what you are asking me to. I started studying 5 days ago.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please I don't know how to do what you are asking me to. I started studying 5 days ago.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` instead of `opendir`/`readdir`? The latter are more standard, but as you've seen, they return UTF-8 encoded strings, which then get interpreted in the locale encoding when printed, not UTF-8. If you used widechar APIs exclusively (`FindFirstFileW`/`FindNextFileW`/`wprintf`), you'd consistently be working in locale independent UTF-16.

Comment: Please @ShadowRanger can you show how it is done? I went in search of it, but couldn't get the headers to run it.

Comment: @surge10: Huh? Couldn't get the headers? It's just `windows.h`, like basically everything in the WinAPI (the docs claim `fileapi.h` works, but recommends including `windows.h`). There are a *bazillion* examples, including on [the docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) (the example uses the dual ANSI/Unicode versions that differ based on preprocessor definitions, but in the modern era, it's reasonable to just write to the `W` suffixed names consistently, or always define `UNICODE` and use the unsuffixed/t-prefixed names).

Comment: `static void hex_dump_byte_string(const char *tag, const char *data) { printf("%s (%zu bytes):\n", tag, strlen(data)); int length = 0; const char *pad = ""; for (size_t i = 0; data[i] != '\0'; i++) { length += printf("%s0x%.2X", pad, (unsigned char)data[i]); pad = " "; if (length > 78) { putchar('\n'); length = 0; pad = ""; } } if (length > 0) putchar('\n'); }` — called as `hex_dump_byte_string("File name", d->d_name);` in your main program after you've printed the file name (`printf("File name: [%s]\n", d->d_name);`). Or you could include printing the file name in the function itself.

Comment: I even added a printf statement, right before the hex function call, but nothing come out `Before the hex
Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 9.159 s
Press any key to continue.`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem related to the difficult mapping between the filename encoding used by Windows and the UTF-8 encoding used by the Unix emulation for `opendir` and `readdir`.

Can you try this debugging code so the encoding returned by `readdir` can be further analysed:

```
    DIR *dr;
    struct dirent *d;
    
    dr = opendir(foldername);
    if (dr != NULL) {
        while ((d = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
            char *p;
            printf("d name: ");
            for (p = d->d_name; *p; p++) {
                unsigned char b = *p;
                if (b >= ' ' && b < 0x7F)
                    printf("%c", b);
                else
                    printf("\\x%02x", b);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code breaks. This is what is printed `d name:` Because it breaks

Comment: @chqrlie it prints the same `d name:` and then breaks

Comment: @surge10: what do you mean by *it breaks*?  Can you post a Minimal Reproducible Example that shows the problem along with the details of platform, IDE and execution method?